# is it a common practice to have the static and dynamic versions of a library with the same name?

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I downloaded a library (NAG c libraries to be precise) and both the static and dynamic versions of the library have the same name (libnagc_nag). At the beginning I was having troubles because I was trying to link to the static version in OS X and by default it uses the dynamic library, so I changed the name of the files to distinguish between them (libnagc_nag_s.a and libnagc_nag_d.dylib for OS X and libnagc_nag_d.so in linux).
my question is: Is giving them the same name to both a common practice? Even if so, Is there any problem or disadvantage on changing their names in this way?

Comment: Yes it is a common practice. You should select the right kind of the library with linker flags (`-Bstatic`/`-Bdynamic`).

Comment: and what happens if you want to use the static version of some libraries and the dynamic version of others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the convention to have

```
 libNAME.a
```

and

```
 libNAME.so.VERS
```

with the .a being the static archive. Why do you *want* to add a static library in to your program, though? You'll encounter maintenance difficulties down the track if you do so.

Adding   `-lnagc_nag_d`  to your `LDFLAGS` in the Makefile should be sufficient to get the dynamic library linked in.

Comment: once I modify the names to libnagc_nag_s.a and libnagc_nag_d.so.V it is easy to add them with the flag, but the trouble is when they have the same name, so -lnagc_nag_d doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to add both static and dynamic forms to your application? You need one or the other, and I strongly recommend the dynamic form.

Comment: no, I want to add only one, which is actually the static version (it's a small scientific application that wont be used many times). The thing is that when I was doing it i realized the fact that both, the static and the dynamic use the same command because they have the same name. This raised my curiosity, and now I'm trying to figure out how do programmers usually select the version they want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can provide a full library's file name to the linker (as of an object file)...

Comment: thanks, that works. Though, the reason I'm asking is mostly to understand the behaviors of the linker, and to gain some insight in common practices.